# JSF h:selectManyCheckbox valueChangeEventListener not fired when user unchecks all

Tags: jsf

My problem is that when the user unchecks everything (leaving 0 checkboxes checked) JSF does not fire the valueChangeListener.

I appreciate any help, thanks.

**JSPX:**

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox           
    value="#{EME01.selectedMaterials}"
    valueChangeListener="#{EME01.materialsValueChangeListener}"
    onchange="submit();">           
    <f:selectItems value="#{EME01.materials}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

**Backing bean (EME01):**

```
public void materialsValueChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent e) {
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider using a name that's slightly less cryptic than `EME01`. You could read the book Clean Code if you need training on choosing good names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For checkboxes (and radio buttons) you're rather interested in `click` event than the `change` event.

```
onclick="submit()"
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, consider using Ajax for this as it's pretty bad user experience to submit the entire form and have a flash of content on every change/click of the checkbox. If you're already on JSF2 for example, use `<f:ajax>` instead.

Comment: hey thanks for your immediate response! .actually i found out that it was my bad, wont delete this question in the hope that someone else made the same mistake: The problem was with required="true", empty values prevented the listener from being called. thanks for the ajax suggestion